# Docker image work well in docker run container but not in swarm

Tags: mysql, docker, swarm

I have a Dockerfile :

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

COPY ./mysql-init.sh /etc/

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  mariadb-server \
  mariadb-client \
  && docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli && \
  chmod +x /etc/mysql-init.sh && /etc/init.d/mysql start && /etc/mysql-init.sh 

COPY ./public-html/ /var/www/html/

CMD service mysql start && service apache2 start && bash
```

Build image with :

```
docker build -t vhost .
```

and run container with :

```
 docker run -dt -p 8080:80 --name test vhost
```

every thing work well and this is the container log :

```
[ ok ] Starting MariaDB database server: mysqld.
[....] Starting Apache httpd web server: apache2ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
. ok
```

but in swarm when i create a service with :

```
docker service create -p 8080:80 --name test vhost
```

service failed and restart again . This is the service log :

```
test.1.5ywz5uq6p9qc@docker-VirtualBox    | Starting MariaDB database server: mysqld.
test.1.5ywz5uq6p9qc@docker-VirtualBox    | ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
test.1.5ywz5uq6p9qc@docker-VirtualBox    | AH00557: apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for 58ff827d9d51
test.1.5ywz5uq6p9qc@docker-VirtualBox    | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
.
.
.
test.1.vvd65rc7xxco@docker-VirtualBox    | Starting Apache httpd web server: apache2.
test.1.u5nepc5a1jib@docker-VirtualBox    | Starting MariaDB database server: mysqld.
test.1.u5nepc5a1jib@docker-VirtualBox    | ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
test.1.u5nepc5a1jib@docker-VirtualBox    | AH00557: apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for 1cd85211c4a7
test.1.u5nepc5a1jib@docker-VirtualBox    | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
.
.
.
```

how can i make service run once and keep running?

Comment: This looks like you want two separate containers (for MySQL and Apache).  The container you have now is a container that principally runs an interactive shell (which probably fails in Swarm) and happens to run the "interesting" things as side effects.

Comment: hi David .Actually i am going to build a hosting and i need a container contain apache php and mariadb in one container for each host . Do you have any Idea to solve this?

Comment: A virtual machine more naturally supports an init system with a supervisor and multiple processes.  You can use tools like Ansible to install software in a VM, and tools like Packer to build fixed VM images depending on your specific virtualization technology.  If you _really_ want to run this in Docker you can, but it's important that your main process not be an interactive shell.

Answer (score -1):

Ok i solve it . when i start apache service in container it return this warning :

```
test.1.5ywz5uq6p9qc@docker-VirtualBox    | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

and this is a warning but i think it return error status and service failed . i change Dockerfile to this and problem solved :

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

COPY ./mysql-init.sh /etc/

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  mariadb-server \
  mariadb-client \
  && docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli && \
  chmod +x /etc/mysql-init.sh && /etc/init.d/mysql start && /etc/mysql-init.sh 

COPY ./public-html/ /var/www/html/

CMD service mysql start ; service apache2 start ; sleep infinity
```